# if $f^2(x)$ is uniformly continuous then f is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[this is the real question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SRoY.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SRoY.jpg)I saw this question like if f is from R to infinity and continuous if g(x)=$f^2(x)$ if g(x) is uniformly continuous so is f(x)
$f^2(x)=f(x)*f(x)$

---

My Thought:
1)for sequence $x_n$ and $y_n$ are like $d(x_n,y_n)$ tends to 0 then $d(g(x_n),g(y_n))$ tends to 0 as g is uniformly continuous .considering usual metric of R(real line) $|g(x)-g(y)|=|f^2(x) -f^2(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)|*|f(x)+f(y)|$ from here how can I show that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ tends to 0
2)first I thought about $\sqrt(x)$ , as it is uniformly continuous and so is g(x) so $\sqrt(g(x))$ will also be uniformly continuous.But as $\sqrt(x)$ is not defined on whole R so I cannot conclude f is uniformly continuous on whole R.

 or there is any counter example.

pleas

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined on whole $\mathbb{R}$ but you are only interested in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Just a small observation: as a multiple choice question this is trivial since all other possibilities can be ruled out easily. (Of course, the fact that $f$ must be  uniformly continuous is not obvious and the question is interesting too. I have given an upvote).

Comment: @freakish ...so it cant be proved for the negative part ?

Comment: @onlymath Yes, right. Well you can extend it to negatives by taking $\sqrt{-x}$.

Comment: @Anvit possibly the above  might solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your point 2 you have proven that $|f|$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x-y|<\delta$, $||f(x)|-|f(y)||<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x-y|<\delta$.

If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have the same sign, then $|f(x)-f(y)| = ||f(x)|-|f(y)||<\frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$.

If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have different signs, then by continuity of $f$ there is $z \in[x,y], f(z)=0$. $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-f(z)| + |f(z)-f(y)| = ||f(x)|-|f(z)|| + ||f(z)|-|f(y)|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.

Comment: You mean $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have same/different signs, right?

Comment: Good catch, editing

Comment: Cute answer by RcnSc

Answer (score 0):

Composition of two uniformly continuous is uniformly continuous . Now take $g(x)=f^2(x)$ and $h(x)=\sqrt(x)$ it is also uniformly continuous .Now think $h(g(x))$???

Comment: I thought like that but square root function isn't defined for all R..so I am having a confusion about uniform continuity on whole R

Comment: @Anvit I didnt get that ...we are composing two functions and $\sqrt(g(x))=\sqrt(f(x)*f(x))$ uniformly continuous for the positive part ..but what if  f(x) for x less than 0 is confusing me

Comment: But $h:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$

Comment: @onlymath I'm not sure about this answer either. Ask @G C R

Comment: h=f for the positive part ...so how can I show f is uniform  for nagetive part

Comment: I think $|f|$ uniformly cont implies $f$ is too. I'm writing a proof wait a bit

Comment: @onlymath $h(g(x))=\sqrt{g(x)} $ now think about codomain of $g(x)$ which is domain of $h(x)$

Comment: yeah but @G C R proved the result for h(x)....possibly answer of freakish above will work

Answer (score 0):

Following your second idea, you need to show that if $f$ is continuous and $\sqrt{g}=|f|$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is also uniformly continuous.  To get some intuition about the situation, come up with an example of a function $f$ such that $|f|$ is continuous, but $f$ is not.  From this, you should see why it might be natural to divide the domain into two parts: $\{|f(x)| \ge \varepsilon\}$ and $\{|f(x)| < \varepsilon\}$.

Comment: I have thought that f(x)=x+1 for x greater than equal to 0 and x-1 otherwise....but didnt get the point you are making..please help

Answer (score 0):

$f^2$ is uniformly cont $\implies (|x-y|<\delta\implies|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|<\epsilon) \implies 
|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|<{\epsilon\over\delta}|x-y|\implies {|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|\over|x-y|}<{\epsilon\over\delta}\implies|2f(x)f'(x)|<{\epsilon\over\delta}\implies |f'(x)|<{k\over |f(x)|}<\frac k {inf \,f}$
If $inf f\ne 0$, we are done since Derivative is bounded implies function is uniformly continous.
Now comes the really non rigourous part.
Let $K=\{x||f(x)|<1\}$. Since $f$ is cont, $f'(x)<M\,\,\forall x\in K$ for some $M\in \mathbb N,$ also $f'(x)<k\,\,\forall x\in\mathbb R\cap K^c$
Thus, $f'$ is bounded and hence $f$ in uniformly continuous

Comment: I may be wrong but g(x) or f(x) might not be differentiable...and one more question you have written R K what it means?

Comment: Was Supposed to be R\K meaning $R\cap K^c$ but you cant directly type '\' in mathjax. Edited in. and Yes you are correct. They may not be differentiable. My solution assumes that though. The one you have selected is great though